# Customizing CSL Editor inline citation for multiple

Tags: inline, mendeley, csl

I am trying to edit one of the preexisting citation style in NP++. I want to change [1],[2],[3],[5],[8] and [1-3],[5],[8] to [1,2,3,5,8]. My coding abilities are below normal. Please suggest how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

your best bet here is to use the CSL editor, see our intro guide here: http://support.mendeley.com/customer/portal/articles/895771-getting-started-with-the-visual-csl-editor

Specifically, you'll want to edit your style, then click 'Layout' under 'Inline Citations' and add a [ prefix and a ] suffix. Then, expand the 'Layout' node and click the 'Group', then remove the [ prefix and the ] suffix.

You can then save the citation style as explained in the above link.

If that doesn't help or you have problems, you might get a quicker response if you contact us through our support page: support.mendeley.com